# Refresh parent component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have two components componentA and componentB. Included ComponentB inside componentA

e.g.

```
<!--Component A-->
<aura:component>

<!--Component B-->
<aura:iteration>
      <c:componentB prod="{!prod}"/>
</aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

I want to refresh parent component (componentA) if user deletes any product from componentB. Delete functionality is working fine but the issue is that i am not able to refresh parent component from child.

Comment: Have a look at events https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_example.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Lightning Events, you need first to create event.

You can create application event or component event.

This is the code for component event sample.

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT">
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

Then you need to define your event in your child component like this

```
<aura:registerEvent name="lightningEvent" type="c:LightningEvent"/>
```

and fire it somewhere in your code. Either in controller or in helper. It is usually better to have it in helper.

```
// on delete inside component B
var event = component.getEvent("lightningEvent");
event.setParam("message", "the message to send" );
event.fire();
```

On the next step you need to define handler for the event in your parent component like this.

```
<aura:handler name="lightningEvent" event="c:LightningEvent" action="{!c.handleEvent}"/>
```

The name and type should match the values on the definition.

Also you need to define method handleEvent in controller

```
handleEvent: function(component, event, helper) {
    // refresh Component A here
    var message = event.getParam("message");
    alert(message);
}
```

Comment: @NileshBorse You are welcome