# Lightning refresh Event isnot working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have component structure like this:

```
 component1
           component A
           component 2
Component 2
        component c
```

Based on button click on ***component c***.I have to refresh ***component1***.

I refered below post

[Refresh parent component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197396/refresh-parent-component?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

everything is working fine, but below line shows error

```
 $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**force:refreshView** event is a salesforce event (catched by one.app) , not a custom event like in [refresh parent component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197396/refresh-parent-component?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

If you need to use it , you have to declare that the component can fire it

```
<aura:registerEvent name="refreshViewEvent" type="force:refreshView"/>
```

That way, `$A.get('e.force:refreshView')` will return an event and not null