# How to load subcomponent in Lightning without using events

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
 component1
            component A
            component 2
Component 2
         component c
```

I refered below post

[Refresh parent component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197396/refresh-parent-component?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Lightning refresh Event isnot working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220634/lightning-refresh-event-isnot-working/220636#220636)

Based on button click on component c level.I have to load component A in javascript side [client side]

Comment: possible solution with no events (although it is the preferred way) would be using data binding with an attribute and then with the onChange event on your parent you can trigger whatever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create dynamic components using `$A.createComponent()`

See SFDC documentation -> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm

Answer (score 0):

Onclick of a Button you can Call a Dynamically Create a component.If you want Prepoulate value in the component you can pass value via attributes like below.

```
  $A.createComponent("c:TXP_EmailComponent", {
                "email": emailAddress
  },
```